# What's wrong with my loop? Keep getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I keep getting a NoSuchElement Exception at the line `maze[r][c]=scan.next();`. How can I resolve that?

```
  try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
        String infoLine = scan.nextLine();
        int rows=0;
        int columns=0;
        for(int i = 0; i<infoLine.length();i++){
            if(Character.isDigit(infoLine.charAt(i))==true){
                rows = (int)infoLine.charAt(i);
                columns = (int)infoLine.charAt(i+1);
                break;
            }
        }

        String [][] maze = new String[rows][columns];
        int r = 0;
        while(scan.hasNextLine()==true && r<rows){
            for(int c = 0; c<columns;c++){
                maze[r][c]=scan.next();
            }
            r++;
        }
        return maze;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Comparing a boolean to true is the same as just using the boolean itself.  That is, anywhere you have "x == true" you can simply use "x".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this part of your code:

```
    while(scan.hasNextLine()==true && r<rows){  // 1
        for(int c = 0; c<columns;c++){          // 2
            maze[r][c]=scan.next();             // 3
        }                                       // 4
        r++;                                    // 5
    }                                           // 6
```

In line 1 you are checking to make sure that scan has another line available.  But in line 3, you read that line - inside the 2:4 loop.  So if there are more than 1 columns, you will be asking for the next scan more than once - and you only checked to see if there was one next line.  So on the second column, if you're at the end of scan, you try to read from scan even though it's run out.

Try this:

```
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    String infoLine = scan.nextLine();
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < infoLine.length();i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(infoLine.charAt(i))) {
            rows = Character.digit(infoLine.charAt(i), 10);
            columns = Character.digit(infoLine.charAt(i + 1), 10);
            break;
        }
    }

    String [][] maze = new String[rows][columns];
    int r = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextLine() && r < rows) {
        int c = 0;
        while(scan.hasNextLine() && c < columns) {
            maze[r][c]=scan.next();
            c++
        }
        r++;
    }
    return maze;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Well, you have an expectation in your code, that your scan has enough entries to cover all of your columns.  Your data violates that expectation.  You could change the inner `for` loop to match the format of your outer `while` loop - and include a hasNextLine() check - but that would exit in the middle of a line.  If you're OK with that, then that might be your solution.  If not, you need to rethink this at a higher level.

Comment: I believe your determinations of rows and columns are in error.  `rows = (int)infoLine.charAt(i);` will get the ascii value of the int, but it appears that what you really want is the integer represented by the char.  `rows = Character.digit(infoLine.charAt(i), 10);` may be the best way to get this.

Comment: What does the 10 do in the digit param?

Comment: Also, that loop causes the columns to max out and not let any column except the last one fill

Comment: Oops!  I forgot to re-initialize c for each row.  Fixed.

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29 for an explanation of the 10 (radix) parameter.